# I get an error during Gulp installation

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-install

I'm trying to setup Gulp on my system. As I type in the command "npm install gulp" in the command prompt, I'm shown an error [image: error shown during installation]. Please help me install Gulp. I access the command prompt from my office which has limited internet access.

Answer (score 0):

It says npm cannot connect to its registry, try to use npm install with another key. It shouldn't work too.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Try to run this on command.